# Promise recursive function not resolved

Tags: node.js, request

I would like to execute a function that will test a first request with a proxy and another without a proxy.

My test works, but my Promise is not resolved if the function restarts :

```
const downloadFile = (configuration, proxy = true) => {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    // Save variable to know progress
    let receivedBytes = 0;
    let totalBytes    = 0;
    let requestFile = {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${configuration.token}`
      },
      url: configuration.remoteFile
    };

    if (proxy) {
      requestFile = { ...requestFile, proxy: `${process.env.PROXY}:${process.env.PROXY_PORT}` };
    }

    console.log(requestFile);

    const out = fs.createWriteStream(configuration.localFile);


    const req = request(requestFile);

    req.pipe(out);

    req
      .on('response', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.statusCode === 200) {
          totalBytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
          configuration.onStart();
        } else {
          console.log(data.statusCode);
        }
      })
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        // Get progress if callback exists
        if (configuration.hasOwnProperty('onProgress')) {
          receivedBytes += chunk.length;
          configuration.onProgress(receivedBytes, totalBytes);
        } else {
          return receivedBytes += chunk.length;
        }
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);

        if (proxy) {
          downloadFile(configuration, false);
        }
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('end');
        resolve(configuration.onEnd());
      });

  });
};
```

If the first request returns an error, I pass in the second, then in my event `end`. But the Promise is not resolved :(

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly code to emit end event from error event . This will resolve 
promise .

```
         req.on('response', (data) => {
            // some code
          })
          .on('data', (chunk) => {
           // some code
          })
          .on('error', (error) => {
             this.emit("end");
          })
          .on('end', () => {
            resolve();
          });
```